# Definite integral problem /doubt

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the integral 
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin x - x^2}{3-|x|}\ dx $$
I have tried splitting the integral at $0$ and then separating the denominator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin x - x^2}{3-|x|}\ dx$$

Then

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{3-|x|}\ dx-\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^2}{3-|x|}\ dx$$

Notice the first term is odd while the second is even. Hence

$$I=-2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2}{3-x}\ dx$$

Comment: And here I am with the antiderivate in terms of logarithms, sign functions, and the fresnel integral. This is much better!